# WFFM - File size and File type validation not working in 8.1 160523

Tags: wffm, custom-field

I am working with WFFM File upload and was asked to restrict File Size and File types. So I created a custom field that inherits the OOTB Upload File of WFFM in order to accommodate the restrictions.

I have tried the ideas in below links..

https://sitecorejunkie.com/2014/04/06/restrict-certain-files-from-being-attached-to-web-forms-for-marketers-forms-in-sitecore/

https://jonathanrobbins.co.uk/2015/10/06/sitecore-marketplace-module-secure-file-upload/

However, both references seem not working in my machine. I have tried debugging it but not debugging on point. I am not sure if the references stated above work in WFFM 8.1 160523 as it requires an MVC Field.

[image: File Size Validator]

[image: File Upload]

Please advice me on this.

Comment: Are you using WFFM MVC or Webforms?

Comment: I'm using WFFM MVC.

Comment: Check https://ggullentops.blogspot.be/2016/05/sitecore-wffm-mvc-fileuploadfield.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On https://ggullentops.blogspot.be/2016/05/sitecore-wffm-mvc-fileuploadfield.html I have a solution for a custom field that can check filesize and type.

Without copying the whole code, it comes down to creating a validation attribute(s) that inherit from DynamicValidationBase and override ValidateFieldValue.

Next you create the custom field: inherit from the base FileUploadField in Sitecore.Forms.Mvc.ViewModels.Fields and override the "Value" property, just to add the custom created attributes.

Register the field in Sitecore (Assembly, class and mvc type) and you're good to go. Start using the field in a mvc form, but do not forget to fill in the necessary parameters as required by the validator(s).

Comment: Hi, I've seen this code before and implemented it. And now is working! Last time I tried it, I did the parameters in the validation. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is for the latest version of Sitecore. If you are finding a way to `create a custom validation rule in Sitecore to handle this on a specific image field on a template` then you can consider my brief answer in a dedicated blog **[here](https://dev.to/tsaxena4k/custom-image-size-limiter-media-type-checker-in-sitecore-3809)**. The Ask or the Task to achieve is listed below - the solution for which I have provided in the blog itself.

## Ask

The requirement was to limit image size on a image field in any template and also to restrict the type of image.

For example: **The image should be less then 1 MB & should be either png or jpg**.